# X-Frame-Options is not working 100% to all pages

Tags: iis, http-headers, x-frame-options

I have something weird (at least for me) and would like to have some help.

I have my website https://www.myweb.com (just for example) and when I hit that website, I am redirected to the login page https://www.myweb.com/Account/Logon, that is fine.

I got a report that my website is missing the X-Frame-Options, so I am checking for that and when I run this command:

curl -I https://www.myweb.com = I do NOT see the Options, but when I run this:
curl -I https://www.myweb.com/Account/Logon = I DO see the Options there.

But, that report is saying that I am missing the directive in this URL:
https://myweb.com/Error/Error?aspxerrorpath=/bundles/

To access the URL above, I do not need to be authenticated.

So, my question is:

- Why I do not see the Options in that URL?
- How can I apply a config that will be done in the entire site/pages?

I am running IIS and ASP.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there are multiple way to add the X-Frame-Options in the response header by using javascript, webconfig, server codes and so on.

If you want to configure IIS to send the X-Frame-Options header, add this to your site's Web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
  ...

  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="sameorigin" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>

  ...
</system.webServer>
```